# Overlap two gif animations without getting System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, winforms, animated-gif

Hello I am just trying to create one of my first games and for that I decided to use gif animations but somehow after clicking by mouse the application instead of changing animation collapses with single message not even in error bar saying:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

Code:

```
bool shoot = false;
    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();           
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ballon_grey.Location = new Point(ballon_grey.Location.X,ballon_grey.Location.Y - 5);        
    }
    private void ballon_grey_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        shoot = true;
        if (shoot == true)
        {
            ballon_grey.Image = Image.FromFile("baloon_explosion.gif");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` - That's pretty explanatory.  It couldn't find the file.  Based on your current code, it's going to look in the directory the program is executing from (most likely bin\debug in your project).

Comment: Did you confirm that the files exist? You're spelling "balloon" in multiple ways, none of them correct.

Comment: @Tim both gif files are saved in project file/Resources

Comment: @DanielMann that is only a spelling mistake.

Comment: if its in your resources all you need is this - ballon_grey.Image = YourApplication.Properties.Resources.baloon_explosion;

Comment: your welcome,i will post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its in your resources all you need is this:

```
ballon_grey.Image = YourApplication.Properties.Resources.baloon_explosion;
```